# Create two way table and change to data frame format

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data as below. I can convert it into format that I want. Second last line gives me the required format. But when I convert into a dataframe I loose the format. How could I keep the format while converting to a dataframe?

```
start_city=c("a","b","a")
end_city=c("b","a","a")
travel=data.frame(start_city,end_city)
table(start_city,end_city)
abc=data.frame(table(start_city,end_city))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to convert it to `matrix` first

```
tbl <- table(start_city, end_city)
res <- as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)
str(res)
#'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ a: int  1 1
#$ b: int  1 0
```

Here, we will loose the `names` of `dimnames` of 'tbl' output

Comment: is there any easy way to know whether start_city is in columns or whether it is in rows? Can I print this information in the dataframe itself?

Comment: @user2543622  It is in the row/column order.  You can check the `dimnames(tbl)`.  But, suppose, you want to also print this info, you may need to create a custom print method

Comment: as per your comment if I use `table(start_city, end_city)` then start_city will be in rows and end_city in columns right?

Comment: @user2543622  If you look at the values in 'tbl' and 'res', it is in the same order.  Nothing changed.  To understand it better, you can change the values of 'end_city' i.e. `end_city <- c("b","a", "c");
table(start_city, end_city)`